# Let $y_1=\sin(x)$ and $y_2=\cos(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following functions are linearly independent from $y_1, y_2$?

A.  $2\cos(x)$

B.  $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

C.  $0$

D.  $\sin^2(x)$

E.  $\sin(2x)$

It may have more than one answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of linear independence ? Where do you get stuck ?

Comment: I just don't know where to start, its preliminary exercise module, so he hasn't really went over anything in class yet, but still wants us to try.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Can you express $2\cos(x)$ as a linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$? What about $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$? Note that $0$ is always an element of every vectorspace hance it is also an element of the vectorspace spanned by $y_1$ and $y_2$. Can you explain why?
For the last question rewrite $\sin(2x)=\sin(x+x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin(x)$ and compare with a linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

For a more formal approach use the Wronskian determinant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian.